# How to reduce dropbox internal data usage

Tags: internal-storage, insufficient-memory, internal-sd, dropbox

Currently both the DiskUsage app and Android's App Data show that Dropbox is using over 800 MB of internal sdcard storage space. Dropbox says it has no offline files. `/storage/sdcard0/Android/data/com.dropbox.android` shows no significant data usage.

Is there a way to clean this up without using the CLEAR DATA button in App Data? What will be the repercussions of using that button?

Answer (score 1):

I have a rooted phone, and I found an > 800 MB file at `:/data/data/com.dropbox.android/global/external/docpreviews`. I just deleted it. This did result in additional free space, though I'm not sure if it will stay free or if there will be other repercussions.